# multiple separate arguments in 'tidyr's separate function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have an issue about separation of one column into multiple columns.

The string example I want to separate is something like '87 BestMovie.GOOD'
separate locations are space `' '` and `'.'`

I tried like this

```
df=data.frame(Eastwood=c('87 BestMovie.GOOD'))
sep=df%>%
separate(Eastwood,into=c('age','Select','Movie'),sep=c(' ','.'))
```

> Warning messages:
>       1: Too many values at 1 locations: 2 
>       2: Too few values at 1 locations: 1

or for another perspective, can we implement string locations for separation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"sep" needs to be a single character value representing a regular expression.  Do this:

```
df %>% separate(Eastwood,into=c('age','Select','Movie'),sep=" |\\\\.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much thc!

Comment: Might be better for to use the character class `\\s` instead of " ".

Comment: @JakeKaupp What does '\\' means anyway?

Comment: `\s` is the regex character class for space, `\.` is for a period or dot.  In r, these have to be escaped with another blackslash so it ends up being `\\s`